# Why CSS Background position changes on sprite height change?

Tags: html, css, sprite, background-position

Something interesting happens in my website. It is in active development and I keep adding and adding stuff to the website's sprite PNG file. Sometimes I add so many icons and blocks that I NEED to change the height of the image, but when I do this, some (NOT ALL!) elements appear on different locations.

For example I have a PNG image with size 900x900 pixels. I mapped the CSS styles to the proper coordinates, they I added 200 pixels of transparent space at the bottom of the image and some styles report different positions :< breaking stuff around the website. So each time I increase the sprite file, I have to open various CSS files and add X pixels (the amount of height I've added). I even added a 1px baseline on the top of the sprite so that I would be certain that I am not changing any positions but just the height.

I read the specification even in the RFCs and the coordinate system start is at x=0,y=0 which is the top left corner of the image. It doesn't make sense to me :(

*UPDATE: Some of the containers that give me bugs are made with positive coordinates rather than negative. I still can't explain it to myself, why stuff like that happens.*

UPDATE: So the sprite is located at this URL http://lucho.hoolwars.com/img/sprites.png

and here are few styles that change coordinates if the height of the sprite changes

```
.job-summary {
width: 330px;
height: 45px;
background: transparent url(/img/sprites.png) -15px 435px;
cursor: default;
}

.popup-title {
background: url('../img/sprites.png') -425px -1077px transparent;
width: 275px;
color: black;
font-weight: normal;
}

.popup-close {
position: absolute;
background: url('../img/sprites.png') -771px -972px transparent;
right: -9px;
top: -22px;
width: 38px;
height: 38px;
z-index: 2;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Each time I change the height of "sprites.png" those coordinates are no longer valid :|

Comment: can we see your website..?

Comment: I'm afraid not, I only have developer environment right now but I could show the sprite and example CSS.

Comment: yes please - otherwise people can only guess at what might be the issue.

Comment: Updated the main post!

Comment: negative pixel values suggest that the distance is from the "bottom" and.or "right" of your sprite. If they were all positive values you probably wouldn't have this problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know whats going on. Hard to explain - but I'll give it a shot.

I believe you have configured some of your sprite images based on the repeating background, because you are not using `no-repeat`. Every time you add more images to the sprite any icons that were configured on a repeated image will shift.

You will need to:

1) Add `no-repeat` to your background (any icons that were using a repeated image will probably now be blank)

2) Reconfigure all your classes to use negative values (always use **negative** values for your image sprites)

I would suggest you setup your sprites similar to this:

**CSS**

```
.sprite-map {
  background: url(sprites.png) no-repeat;
}

.job-summary {
  background-position: -80px 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
}

.popup-title {
  background-position: -15px -100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.popup-close {
  background-position: -15px -472px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="job-summary sprite-map"></div>
<div class="popup-title sprite-map"></div>
<div class="popup-close sprite-map"></div>
```

That way you only need to specify the URL to the sprite once. Now when you add images to the bottom or the right of the sprite - nothing else will be affected.

Also if you're familiar with Sass - Compass makes image sprites incredibly easy. It might be worth taking a look at if you're interested: http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/

Hope this helps!